# Sound through both headphones and HDMI monitor speakers?

Tags: windows-7, audio

Is there a way to get sound to come out both my monitor’s speakers and my headphones at the same time?

- **OS:** Windows 7 Home Premium
- **Monitor:** [ASUS VE247H](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/VE247H/overview/) (Connected via HDMI)
- **Headphones:** Plugged into back panel (audio out)

Comment: Try this http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/226248-how-enable-my-laptop-speakers-headphones-same-time.html

Comment: This works, thank you! But now I also wonder if there's a way to eliminate the delay on the listening device.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get sound to come out both my monitor’s speakers and
>   my headphones at the same time?

Buy one of those 3.5" headphone jack splitters.

[image]